# primefaces fileupload and download PDF

Tags: oracle, jsf, pdf, file-upload, primefaces

Please, can anyone tell how can i implement some code to upload a PDF file to my database, using Primefaces ou just JSF? 
The entity property is a BLOB.

att,

Diego Sabino

Comment: Anybody can help with this problem?

Comment: Including yourself, or Google? Show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to look at this example

[Prime Faces File Example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadDnd.jsf)

This gives you the File object.

Then you can save this to the database as

```
//saving the image
            PreparedStatement psmnt = (PreparedStatement)    con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DB.images VALUES(?,?)");
            psmnt.setInt(1, 5);
            psmnt.setBlob(2, new FileInputStream(fileFromEvent), fileFromEvent.length());
            psmnt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Image saved in DB");
```